# How to display MySQL content in an HTML table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a MySQL database that I've imported a huge list of domains into - they're all in one table and it's the only column - very simple ;)

I want to display domains on my website similar to here:  http://www.statmyweb.com/archive/43001/

I'd like to have 1000 domains listed per page and at the bottom of each page it should have a links such as "Previous Page" and "Next Page".

It seems extremely simple, I'm just not familiar with coding and none of my efforts have worked.  If someone could post the code for it when they have time it would be great appreciated.

Comment: There are millions of sites when somebody did "post the code" online. Please report your efforts, and we will be glad to help you - but not cheap code monkeying here!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
<?php
 $start=0;
 $limit=10;//your limit of elements in 1 page
 $query='your query';
 //execute query and take total row count into $totalRows
 if(isset($_GET['start']))
 {
 $start=$_GET['start'];
 }
 $query.=" LIMIT ".$start.",".$limit;
 // execute query and count into $currentRows
 ?>

 <html>
  <body>
   <table>
   <?php
   for($i=0;$i<$currentRows; $i++){
   ?>
   <tr><td colspan='2'><?php echo value here?></td></tr>
   <?php
   }
   ?>
   <?php
if($start>0)
{
$prev   =   $start-$limit;
}
else
{
$prev   =   $start;
}
if(($start+$limit)<$totalRows)
{
$next   =   $start+$limit;
}
else
{
$next   =   $start;
}
?>
   <tr><td><a href='yourpage.php?start=<?php echo $prev; ?>'>Previous</a></td><td><a href='yourpage.php?start=<?php echo $next; ?>'>Next</a></td></tr>
   </table>
  <body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In mysql select query add limit 1000 then print only 1000 record at a time and make previous and next page link and increment it 1000

```
<?php 
$previous=$_REQUSEST['limit'];
if($previous>0)
{
echo "<a href='index.php?limit=1000-".$previous."'>Previous</a>";
}

echo "<a href='index.php?limit=1000+."$previous."'>Next</a>";
?>
```

Comment: `1000+/-$previous` won't be computed.

Comment: and "$previous" will probably be 0 ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$i= 0;
$j= 1;

$return_html = '<table>';
$total_count = count($database_results);
foreach ($database_results as $row){
   if($i == 0){
       $return_html .= '<tr>';
   }
   $return_html .= '<td>' . $row . '</td>;

   if($i == 3 || $j == $total_count){
       $return_html . '</tr>';
   }

if($j == $total_count){
   $return_html .] '</table>';
}

   i++;
   j++;
}
```

That's how to build the table. other answer explains the rest.